# Can OpenVPN (Linux) connect through a jump server?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, fedora, openvpn

I use MacOS at work, where I connect to a VPN (using Tunnelblick). We use a "jumpbox" to proxy requests to the VPN server itself. I have an ovpn file, username and password for the VPN, plus a username and pem file to get into the jump server.

In Tunnelblick, there's an option for assigning a proxy server and username/cert file. I don't see such an option using OpenVPN on Linux (Fedora 29) using the default network manager GUI for KDE (kcm_networkmanagement). Is there a way to use a jump server in Fedora's OpenVPN client? If not, is there another OpenVPN client that might work?

I've tried Frohu client, but I don't see any jump server / proxy options there. I've also tried using OpenVPN from the command line, but openvpn --config  never asks for a proxy option, and the man page help doesn't seem to support jump servers, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your setup: If you ssh into the jumpbox, use ssh with port forwarding (e.g. `-L`), point your local OpenVPN to the forwarded local ssh port, see if it works. IIRC ssh only port forwards TCP, so your VPN will need to use TCP, too. Not sure if the automatic setup OpenVPN does will get confused by this, you may have to fiddle with it (disable and replace with manual setup as necessary).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenVPN connection through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/1356330/openvpn-connection-through-ssh-tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively a [duplicate of this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1356330/openvpn-connection-through-ssh-tunnel/), for which I gave an answer, though **no** answer wasn't accepted by the OP.