# Connect to a VPN through a SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I'm in a quite locked network, but I can reach a server outside through SSH.

Using a SSH jump, I can SSH on a Pi at home, which also host a VPN (PiVPN setup, TCP)

Is it technically possible using SSH LocalForward or DynamicForward to connect to my VPN ?

This is my `.ssh/config` :

```
Host home
Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
Port 22
User myuser
ForwardAgent yes
ProxyJump jumpserver
#tried this
#LocalForward 1194 127.0.0.1:1194
#and this
DynamicForward 2280
```

When I'm trying to connect to my VPN the following messages appears in my ssh'd terminal
`channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

Am I missing something or is it not possible ?

Thanks

EDIT:

OpenVPN was not started (failed to start using a 1024bits key).

So, it's now connected but it seems that there's no traffic.
I found this : [OpenVPN connection through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/1356330/openvpn-connection-through-ssh-tunnel)
I'm quite sure there's a problem with a route, but I'm not understanding what to do with the line
`route REMOTE-IP 255.255.255.255 net_gateway default`

Adding this line to the ovpn file makes it failed to be load

EDIT 2 :

`.ssh/config`

```
Host jumpserver
    HostName IP_JUMP_SERVER
    User USER_JUMP
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand nc -x WORKPLACE_PROXY:1080 -X 5 %h %p

Host vpnssh
    Hostname IP_HOME_SERVER
    Port 2222
    User USER_SSH_HOME_SERVER
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyJump jumpserver
    DynamicForward 2280
```

`> ssh vpnssh`

This part works perfectly, I leave this ssh connection within its terminal.

I can use ssh tunnel as firefox proxy `localhost:2280` : Works, browsing like at home.

ovpn file :

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote IP_HOME_SERVER 2294
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_RMxyuSg5Snuj0qfa name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
#set socks proxy (use ssh tunnel dynamic fwd)
socks-proxy localhost 2280
socks-proxy-retry
#set a route to my server public ip
route IP_HOME_SERVER 255.255.255.255 net_gateway default
<ca>
...
</ca>
<cert>
...
</cert>
<key>
...
</key>
<tls-auth>
...
</tls-auth>
```

`> sudo openvpn --config home_vpn.ovpn`

openvpn connection logs (without date/times for clarity) :

```
DEPRECATED OPTION: http-proxy-retry and socks-proxy-retry: In OpenVPN 2.4 proxy connection retries are handled like regular connections. Use connect-retry-max 1 to get a similar behavior as before.
OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280
Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280 [nonblock]
TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280
TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280, sid=19fd4888 c3beb792
VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
VERIFY KU OK
Validating certificate extended key usage
++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
VERIFY EKU OK
VERIFY X509NAME OK: CN=server_RMxyuSg5Snuj0qfa
VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_RMxyuSg5Snuj0qfa
Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
[server_RMxyuSg5Snuj0qfa] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:2280
SENT CONTROL [server_RMxyuSg5Snuj0qfa]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,block-outside-dns,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 1800,ping-restart 3600,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:3: block-outside-dns (2.4.4)
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1626
OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
ROUTE_GATEWAY IP_WORKPLACE_GW/255.255.255.128 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.2/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
/sbin/ip route add 127.0.0.1/32 via IP_WORKPLACE_GW
/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
/sbin/ip route add IP_HOME_SERVER/32 via IP_WORKPLACE_GW
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

With this, I can't ping anything or browse. VPN seems connected but any request does not work.

I've also tested using my phone as modem, using the jump server without using `ProxyCommand nc -x WORKPLACE_PROXY:1080 -X 5 %h %p`: Same result.

Thanks for reading this !

EDIT 3 :

Testing outside this network various configs, I just discover that the cause is when the ssh jump is used. Without, that is just working fine.

EDIT 4 :

I think the problem is in fact this :
`ProxyCommand nc -x WORKPLACE_PROXY:1080 -X 5 %h %p`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879297/13317

Comment: ...yes
pivpn was failing to start using a 1024 bits key

Comment: ...but no traffic! (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already referenced [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1356330/openvpn-connection-through-ssh-tunnel/1356991#1356991), and tried to add this line to your config file:

```
route REMOTE-IP 255.255.255.255 net_gateway default
```

Did you add that verbatim?  If so, replace `REMOTE-IP` with the IP (or DNS name) of your remote server.

Comment: YES! Figure it out : route [...] line in .ovpn IS NOT accepted by Linux Mint network tools but do work when using openvpn --config...

Comment: Great! Suggest you add a complete answer to your own question and accept it as the answer so others can benefit from your work.

Comment: It works at home through my thetering test but not at work :(
VPN is connected but no ping nor http traffic..
I don't know where to search

Comment: Suggest you post your current ssh and openvpn configs - it's a bit hard to debug without.  Feel free to replace sensitive IPs or hostnames with proxy names.

Comment: added and EDIT 2 in my original post

Comment: added an EDIT 3 : Found that without ssh jump that works.

Comment: Since you have both an endpoint and a jump host, you'll more than likely have to add a specific route to the jump host as well..  E.g. 'route IP_JUMP_SERVER 255.255.255.255 net_gateway default'.  Think about it this way - if you don't have a (high priority) route entry for the jump host, traffic destined for it will be directed through the VPN.  But the VPN can't send traffic there because it's got to to go through the Jump host.  That's my 2-cent diagnosis...

Comment: does not work..